# store multiple user class instance in tuple embedded in list

Tags: python

I am attempting to store multiple instances of user input objects in a tuple and then store each tuple once in a single list. 
here is my code for the script:

```
class HolidayData:       

    def __init__(self, idnum, dcity):

        self.idnum = idnum  
        self.dcity = dcity 

def main():
    global holiday_data_obj 
    global holiday_database
    holiday_data_obj = []
    holiday_database = []

    while True:
        if input("Add Holiday Package? (y/n) ") == "n":
            break
        else:

            idnum = int(input('Enter your unique id number: '))
            dcity = str(input('Enter your destination city : '))

            add_packages(idnum, dcity)
            print_packages()


def add_packages(idnum, dcity):
    holiday_data_obj.append( HolidayData(idnum, dcity))
    for package in holiday_data_obj:
        F = tuple(package.__dict__.values())
        holiday_database.append(F)

def print_packages():    
            print(holiday_database)
```

here is the output pattern i am getting?

[(1, 'first city'), (1, 'first city'), (2, 'second city'), (1, 'first city'), (2, 'second city'), (3, 'third city')]

i have tried iterating over the holiday_data_object and database_list to check for repeat values but have ended up with the same output pattern.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with your appending logic.  Each time you get a new item, you add the *entire* package list to your "data base".  Thus, the first time, you add only the new package.  The second time, you add the first and second packages.  The third time, you add all three packages.

Add only the newest package on each iteration.  Alternately, gather them all in your package list, and then add them to the data base *only* after the user enters `n`.  Doing both is what causes your problem.

Comment: would you how i add only the newest package to each iteration, I've tried using the "in" to check for similarities to no success

Comment: Where are you stuck?  You *create* object at the first line of `add_packages`.  As I said, add only that, rather than the entire list of packages (the following loop).

Comment: ahh i see. i was stuck on where to append without running into namespace issues